# Convert into a loop in R

Tags: r, loops

I'm new to R and trying to convert the following segments into a loop:

```
tea_s_eachclicks=as.data.frame(matrix(nrow=1,ncol=12))
tea_s_eachclicks$V1=sum(mergetea_s[1:45,119:122]=='2')
tea_s_eachclicks$V2=sum(mergetea_s[1:45,123:126]=='2')
tea_s_eachclicks$V3=sum(mergetea_s[1:45,127:130]=='2')
tea_s_eachclicks$V4=sum(mergetea_s[1:45,131:134]=='2')
tea_s_eachclicks$V5=sum(mergetea_s[1:45,135:138]=='2')
tea_s_eachclicks$V6=sum(mergetea_s[1:45,139:142]=='2')
tea_s_eachclicks$V7=sum(mergetea_s[1:45,143:146]=='2')
tea_s_eachclicks$V8=sum(mergetea_s[1:45,147:150]=='2')
tea_s_eachclicks$V9=sum(mergetea_s[1:45,151:154]=='2')
tea_s_eachclicks$V10=sum(mergetea_s[1:45,155:158]=='2')
tea_s_eachclicks$V11=sum(mergetea_s[1:45,159:162]=='2')
tea_s_eachclicks$V12=sum(mergetea_s[1:45,163:166]=='2')
```

The `mergetea_s` has 12 segments of 4 columns which should be counted into the `tea_s_eachclicks` but only if the value is "2"

Highly appreciate every advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
# Define constants (avoid magic numbers):
rows <- 1:45
cols_ref <- 119:122
n_steps <- 12

# Preallocate
tea_s_eachclicks <- as.data.frame()
for (i in 1:n_steps) { 
  tea_s_eachclicks[[paste0("V", i)]] <- 
    sum(mergetea_s[rows, cols_ref + 4*(i-1)] == '2')
}
```

Couldn't test this since you didn't provide reproducible data.